# How can I use function type?

Tags: swift, swiftui

**I want to know if there is a way to use a function Type as var**, for example in this code I am trying to send a function to get triggered in a Button tap Action. Is this kind of programming even possible in Swift?

**`The down code is not working and It is for SwiftUI, but the question is applicable to Swift as well.`**

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var backgroundColor: Color = Color.white

func backgroundColorFunction() { backgroundColor = Color.red }

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        
        backgroundColor.ignoresSafeArea()
        
        CustomView(incomingFuction: backgroundColorFunction()) // :Here
        
    }
    

}
}



struct CustomView: View {

var incomingFuction: ???funcType??? = ???funcType???()

var body: some View {
    

    Button("update Background Color") {
        
        incomingFuction()
        
    }
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a read through [The Swift Programming language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book). It has an entire section on Closures.

Comment: You can declare a function variable like `var f: () -> Void` for instance but your example is a bit strange since your function updates a @State property in one view but you want to call it from another view and this will not work as it is now, you need to use @Binding for instance and change the signature of the function

Comment: Btw you are trying to call it when passing it. You should drop the `()` when passing it to the initializer `CustomView(incomingFuction: backgroundColorFunction)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, moreover it is widely used, especially in SwiftUI.

Here is your updated code:

```
struct FuncContentView: View {
    
    @State var backgroundColor: Color = Color.white
    
    func backgroundColorFunction() { backgroundColor = Color.red }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            backgroundColor.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            CustomView(incomingFuction: backgroundColorFunction) // << here !!
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView: View {
    
    var incomingFuction: () -> ()   // << here !!
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("update Background Color") {
            incomingFuction()
        }
    }
}
```